# Statistics Similar Number in sets

Tags: probability, statistics

I'am trying to determine what is the likelihood having the same sequence of numbers in a given array.

I have an array of 2 rows and n columns (n is known), I then decided a range (1 to x) let's say 6 for the example, and I populate my array pseudo randomly with numbers in my range. I then have something looking like this

```
1 3 6 1 1 n
4 5 2 2 4 n
```

What I'm trying to determine, is a "formula" which is going to say, you have this much chances of having 1 time the set

```
1
4
```

Or this much chances of having it twice, and this applied for each set, knowing that it is also based on my chosen range, but i haven't been able to figure out a way of doing it yet.

For each number of each row it should be something like

```
 (1/range)
```

but I do not understand how to relate that to the fact that my set is composed of two numbers and n columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use your $6$, though the idea generalizes readily. Imagine that the numbers in the first line represent the $n$ throws of a green die, and the numbers in the second line represent the $n$ throws of a red die. (That's why we kept your $6$.)

Any pattern $(a,b)$ of $a$ on green and $b$ on red has probability $\frac{1}{36}=p$. Call geting that pattern a **success**. The number of successes in $n$ trials has **binomial distribution** with parameters $n$ and $p$. So the probability of exactly $k$ successes is
$$\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.$$ 
In particular, for your example, the probability of getting exactly one $(1,4)$ is $n(1/36)(35/36)^{n-1}$.

Comment: thank you for that answer, so if I wanted to know the probability of getting exactly two $(1,4)$ i would use this $n(1/36)(34/36)^{n-1}$ ? and so on, and I would repeat that if I wanted to know the probability of getting the set $(3,5)$ or should the formula be modified (since I would already have the probability for $(1,4)$)?

Comment: You are welcome. The probability of exactly two $(1,4)$, is, by the formula of the answer, equal to $\binom{n}{2}(1/36)^2(35/36)^{n-2}$. Here $\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.  For $(3,5)$ you use the same procedure. If you want the probability of say two $(1,4)$ **and** one $(1,4)$, the formula does not apply as it stands, but can be modified to give the answer. (We use the multinomial, not the binomial.)

Comment: Thank you for the previous clarification. but would it be the same formula  if I wanted to know the probability of the pattern existing at least once or more ?